# Setting div IDs to dynamic IDs using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am attempting to use Bootstrap accordion to allow a section of text to be expanded upon when a button is clicked.  The data is being pulled from a JS file (Angular), however, I cannot seem to figure how how to set the div ID according to the JS file.

HTML:

```
    <li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">
        <a href="{{i.url}}"><img ng-src="{{i.image}}" /></a>
        <p>{{i.title}}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-desc btn-lg pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{i.id}}">Expand Description/Output</button>
        <div id="{{i.id}}" class="collapse">
        <p>{{i.desc}}</p>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        id: '1',
        url: 'http://google.com',
        title: 'Google',
        image: 'http://google.com/image.png',
        desc: 'Information about Google'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        url: 'http://duckduckgo.com',
        title: 'Duck Duck Go',
        image: 'http://duckduckgo.com/image.png'
        desc: 'Information about Duck Duck Go'
    },
```

I can display properly each entry for url, image, title, but the same application of the {{id}} or {{i.id}} does not seem to work in relation to data-target and div id.  I have looked at other Stack items, but cannot seem to work back from them.

Comment: You cant set an id to an integer. Try item-{{i.id}} or something.

Comment: I did try that, but no action when pressing the button to expand unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

firstly:
In your list item you want searchFor to be filter
i.e.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">
```

should be

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchText">
```

secondly:
You can't set an id to an integer, why not try using:

```
<a href="{{'item-' + i.url}}"><img ng-src="{{i.image}}" /></a>
```

This way you have a string which still has your id value. Although your scope sets the int values to string by default, the HTML will render the id as a int not a string, therefore you want to add text into your statement and that way it's more definitive and you avoid the problem of "why isn't my id working?"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting $index of the repeater as the id

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-desc btn-lg pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{$index}}">Expand Description/Output</button>
 <div id="{{$index}}" class="collapse">
```

Comment: I did set it as this as well, but that did not work and nothing happens when pressing the expand button.